# Beamer: Keep page height when changing aspect ratio

Tags: beamer, paper-size, presentations

I have a presentation that is based onto a 4:3 aspect ratio.
This means that each page has height of 96mm.

It contains a couple of rather complicated figures that I would not like to redo.

Now I have to present it on a 16:9 screen.
The problem: Passing `aspectratio=169` will change the page height to 90mm.

Is there a way to keep the page height fixed when changing aspect ratio?

E.g this will have no text cut off.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item

\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But this will have some text cut off:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item

\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now imagine that page also contains some tikz images with `remember picture, overlay` that paint into that text.
It would be nice if one could fix that without needing to redo everything.

Comment: how you include image on slide? if it is possible include as pdf or similar file, then you can manage image size with options of `includegraphics` without affecting flide size. anothe options is enlarge text block size only for this frame. To be more particular you need to provide MWE which exhabit your problem

Comment: These are not images, but algorithms and (rather complicated) tikz images. the issue is that i do not want to redo spacing of all my elements. I'll get you some MWE in a sec.

Comment: is option to break your list onto more frames?  try to add `allowframebreaks` as option to `frame`.  Off-topic, audince usually not follows to huge and complicate images as well listings and tables. Try to omit them :)

Comment: I just got you a  very minimal working example, this is not a question about slide design. the whole point is that the slides fill the whole screen and consist of images, tikz, algorithms and text. Changing each one of these would be super painful. Hence, I would like a way that just fixes the paper size. If this is not possible, I'd of course also accept that as a valid answer, but the question is not about how to change each and every slide.

Comment: The bigest frame size you can obtain with `aspectratio=1610` if this is still to small, see how to reduce left and right text margin. last option, which offer Beamer is use smaller fonts you reduce font size. Default is 10pt, but you can reduce them to 8pt. More about frame size is not possible to do. And as I already said in previous comment: see if breakeng frames onto more side can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could just use the `\geometry` option (from the geometry package, which beamer already loads) to define your own 16:9 paper size.

```
\documentclass[%
%   aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\geometry{papersize={171mm,96mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item

\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use the same trick as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679017/36296

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=3218]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item

\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item \item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]