# Beamer presentation with 16:9 aspect ratio and same height as 4:3 aspect ratio?

Tags: beamer, paper-size

Beamer 4:3 presentations are a bit taller than the 16:9 ones (see [Beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section *8.3 Frame and Margin Sizes*) :

- `aspectratio=43` : 128 mm by 96 mm  (6mm taller)
- `aspectratio=169` : 160 mm by 90 mm

I would like both aspect ratios to have the same height to be able to easily have a 16:9 presentation when needed without further modifications. For example, with the quarantine lockdown, I'm uploading videos of my presentations, hence I would prefer to use a wider format.

Is it possible to easily customize the dimensions of the 16:9 aspect ratio to have the same height as the 4:3 aspect ratio ?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Minimal Working Example 16:9}
\LARGE
\foreach \i in {0,...,10}
{
  \i\\
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: 4:3 aspect ratio]
[image: 16:9 aspect ratio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beamer` uses `geometry` package to setup paper size. So you can use something similar to

```
% use it before \begin{document}
\geometry{paperwidth=500pt, paperheight=200pt}
```

to change the paper size.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the `aspectratio` option and `\geometry{paperwidth=170.67mm, paperheight=96mm}` did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

With a couple of exceptions, all aspect ratios will produce frames of the same height. They will only differ in the width of the frame.

Unfortunately the `169` aspect ratio is such a special case, but you can get the same ratio with `3218` (or any other multiple of 16 and 9 which aren't too big (the ratio can have 4 digits max)):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=3218]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Minimal Working Example 16:9}
\LARGE
\foreach \i in {0,...,10}
{
  \i\\
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]